# Find duplicate images algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm, duplicates

I want to create a program that find the duplicate images into a directory, something like [this app](https://profesionalsoftware.com/image-cleaner-duplicate-photo-finder-and-remover/) does and I wonder what would be the algorithm to determine if two images are the same.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: How do you define "duplicate"? Do the images have to be identical? Can they have different sizes? Image file formats? File attributes?

Comment: Yes, the two images can have different sizes and different file formats, only the content of the two images to be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task can be solved by [perceptual-hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing), depending on your use-case, combined with some data-structure responsible for nearest-neighbor search in high-dimensions (kd-tree, ball-tree, ...) which can replace the brute-force search (somewhat).

There are tons of approaches for images: DCT-based, Wavelet-based, Statistics-based, Feature-based, CNNs (and more).

Their designs are usually based on different assumptions about the task, e.g. rotation allowed or not?

[A google scholar search on perceptual image hashing](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&q=perceptual+image+hashing&btnG=&lr=) will list a lot of papers. You can also look for the term *image fingerprinting*.

[Here is some older ugly python/cython code doing the statistics-based approach](https://github.com/sschnug/pyVideoHash/blob/master/frame_hash.pyx).

Remark: [Digikam](https://www.digikam.org/) can do that for you too. It's using some older Haar-wavelet based approach i think.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.